# How to reduce the layout size to 75% of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

here I was developing a chat demo app. In my condition is how to set the layout for 75% of the screen? Please, find the attached image [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HhCS.png).
How to reduce the green color chat area to 75%?
Here I have use recyclerview.
This is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bgc1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text Message"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
           />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just use weights and gravity.

Comment: Can you please explain me by coding?

Comment: Can you name the view which you want it to be 75% ? It is not clear from your xml which view you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry, I am getiing Error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_widthPercent' in package.

Comment: Second RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [PercentRelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)? You'll need to add it in as a dependency in gradle

```
  compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.2.1'
```

and then your layout would look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textMessage"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="Text Message"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:background="@drawable/bgc1"
            app:layout_widthPercent="75%"
            />
    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [PercentRelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

*Code Example*

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <ImageView
     app:layout_widthPercent="75%"
     app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
 />
```